# Combine values corresponding to repeated adjacent values in vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, indexing

I have to vectors of data that look something like this:

```
A = [1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 4 3 3 3 3];
B = [1 5 9 6 4 6 8 2 1 5 7 8 3 2 6];
```

I would like to remove all repeated adjacent values in `A` and sum the corresponding values in `B`, with result being

```
A = [1 2 3  4 5 6  5 4  3];
B = [1 5 15 4 6 10 1 12 19];
```

I could use `unique` as described in [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/83795-consolidating-row-values-from-previous-column-duplicate-values#answer_93379), but that would combine all repeated values, duplicate values, regardless of order. I could also use `diff`, as described in [this question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/216921-need-to-remove-repeated-adjacent-elements-in-an-array), but I don't know how to record the indices that would be combined.

I could always just iterate through the vector, but that seems needlessly tedious and I feel there should be a more elegant solution. Is there a way to achieve this in just a couple lines?

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: @rayryeng Finally getting to trying it out, and it does exactly what I need. That trick with `cumsum` and `accumarray` is great!

Comment: Hehe, no problem at all.  `accumarray` and `cumsum` are two of my favourite functions.  I'm glad I got to share those with you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to first find neighbouring locations that are not unique, then combine this with [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) so that you can generate the different groups that should belong to each other.  Finding any values in the difference result that are non-zero will find those values that are non-unique but consecutive.  When you apply `cumsum` to this result, you will generate an ID array that varies from 1 up to as many groups where all values that belong to the same ID belong to the same consecutive group.  This should serve as an ideal input into [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) where we can sum all of the values that belong to each group:

```
Aval = A(:); % Unroll into a column to ensure shape compliance
ind = diff([Inf; Aval]) ~= 0; % Find all unique locations
IDs = cumsum(ind); % Create ID array
Aout = Aval(ind).'; % Determine all unique values per group
Bout = accumarray(IDs(:), B(:)).'; % Find their sum
```

I will admit that this is not in a couple of lines as most of it is setup, but the core answer is seen in the second, third and last line of code.  Notice the subtlety with `accumarray` where the inputs are required to be **column vectors**.  To enforce the inputs so that they're column vectors, I use `(:)` to unroll the vectors into columns regardless of their shape, especially with the first line of code.  I then transpose the result in the end as `accumarray` will output a column vector in this case and transposing will create a row vector, as you would like a row vector as the desired result.

For your test input:

```
A = [1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 4 3 3 3 3];
B = [1 5 9 6 4 6 8 2 1 5 7 8 3 2 6];
```

The output of the `diff` result gives:

```
>> ind.'

ind =

     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
```

You can precisely see that values that are zero correspond to non-unique consecutive positions.  The output of the ID array once you run `cumsum` gives:

```
>> IDs.'

IDs =

     1     2     3     3     4     5     6     6     7     8     8     9     9     9     9
```

Performing `cumsum` on the IDs array transforms this `diff` array so that each consecutive group gives you a unique ID.  We can also use `ind` to index into `A` to find those unique values per group which is the third line.  The last line sums over each group.  Note that the third line is transposed to become a row vector as I unrolled the data so that it's a column vector to begin with.

We get the desired output:

```
>> Aout

Aout =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     5     4     3

>> Bout

Bout =

     1     5    15     4     6    10     1    12    19
```